# How to make the scala compiler find case classes used with wrong arguments

Tags: scala, maven, scalac

I have a `case class Disconnect(nodeId: PublicKey)` that has 1 parameter in it, however in some other part of the code it happened to be used without the parameter i.e: `Disconnect` and the compiler did not catch the error, note that I've also tried to run the compiler with `-Xlint` option and it still can't catch the error.

- scala version: 2.11.12
- target jvm version: 1.8
- code compiled with options:
  `-deprecation`
  `-feature`
  `-language:postfixOps`
  `-language:implicitConversions`
  `-Xfatal-warnings`
  `-unchecked`
  `-Xmax-classfile-name 140`
  `-nobootcp`

[history] It used to be `case object Disconnect` but at some point it has been changed to case class and a parameter was added, in the code it was still instantiated parameterless and the compiler couldn't notice it. I tried adding `-Xlint` option to the compiler but it didn't help.

In Peer.scala

```
  object Peer { 
    // other code
    case class Disconnect(nodeId: PublicKey)
    // more code
  }
```

In Channel.scala

```
  // inside a function
  revocationTimeout.peer ! Peer.Disconnect
  //
```

I expected the compiler to catch the misuse of the case class and fail to compile.

Edit: thanks all for the replies, indeed the compiler is doing his job just fine and `Disconnect` is being used as a type instead of case class instance, this is possible because it's used in a function that accepts `Any` as parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you declare `Disconnect` to be a `case class`, the compiler automatically generates a companion `object Disconnect`, which holds all the neat `apply` and `unapply` methods. Therefore, `Peer.Disconnect` is a perfectly valid expression of the singleton type `Peer.Disconnect.type`. One might argue that it wouldn't have happened if you used Akka Typed right from the beginning, but in your code, the `!` method accepts anything, so in order to force the compiler to emit some meaningful error messages, you need something else. Here is one simple approach:

1. Revert to the state where `Disconnect` was a singleton object, without an associated case class.
2. Remove the `Disconnect` definition altogether. Add `case class NewDisconnect` instead. Now every occurrence of `Peer.Disconnect` will become a *proper error*.
3. Replace all `Peer.Disconnect` by `Peer.NewDisconnect(foo)`
4. Rename `NewDisconnect` to `Disconnect`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in the compiler but in the method [`!`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/e5672727663dc256f4902a4ba84812b7f2eba33c/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/ActorRef.scala#L184) which accepts `Any` as argument:

```
def !(message: Any)(implicit sender: ActorRef = Actor.noSender): Unit
```

so we could change the argument to anything and it would still compile, for example,

```
revocationTimeout.peer ! "woohoo"  // compiles OK!
```

On the other hand if we look at the corresponding Akka Typed [`!`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/e5672727663dc256f4902a4ba84812b7f2eba33c/akka-actor-typed/src/main/scala/akka/actor/typed/ActorRef.scala#L67) method

```
implicit final class ActorRefOps[-T](val ref: ActorRef[T]) extends AnyVal {
    def !(msg: T): Unit = ref.tell(msg)
}
```

then we see it is parameterised with type parameter `T` and the compiler would catch it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `!` is the tell operator from akka actors.

It's signature is

```
def !(message: Any)(implicit sender: ActorRef = Actor.noSender): Unit
```

So you can send to it literally anything, in this case you are sending the type Disconnect.
This is one of the greatest disadvantages from using akka actors, that's why there is a new module [akka typed](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/index.html) where you define a type-safe behavior for your actors.

You may wonder why this doesn't blow up in runtime if you are sending an object that you don't expect. The reason is that actor's receive is a PartialFunction[Any, Unit] that "discards" the messages that are not defined for the PF.